# Bibtex with included files

Tags: bibtex, miktex, include, miktex2.9

A couple weeks ago I didn't have any issue when using Bibtex on a document where the different parts were included with `\include` commands, but today I updated Miktex, and now it seems not to work anymore. Now when I compile the main document I get an error message that says

> I couldn't open auxiliary file section.aux
>
> ---line 3 of file test.aux
>
> : @input{section.aux
>
> : }
>
> I'm skipping whatever remains of this command

Here's a minimal (non)working example : my main file "test.tex" is just

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\include{section}
\bibliography{reference}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

where the file "section.tex" is just

```
\section{My section}
I need to test the citations, so see \cite{A}.
```

and the file "reference.bib" just contains one reference. It works like a charm if I add the section directly or if I `\input` it, but with `\include` it just gives the error message as above. I tried with different editors (Texniccenter, Texmaker, Texstudio and Texworks) and it seemed to have the same issue each time. What is causing this problem ?

P.S. I've looked at an old version of my document that used to work, and I've noticed a difference in the .aux files : the old version has, near the beginning, a line

```
\bbl@cs{beforestart}
```

whereas in the newer versions it seems that this line has become

```
\@nameuse{bbl@beforestart}
```

I'm not sure it's related or if it makes any sense, but I thought I'd add it in case it made a difference.

Comment: Are you using MikTeX or TeX live? Did you update your installation recently?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with a fully updated MikTeX on Windows, but on a TeX live on my Ubuntu virtual machine the MWE works fine (fully self-contained at https://gist.github.com/moewew/3b71b57b60ad134fbc7d48beef7c698e if anyone is interested). If you or anyone else can confirm that this is a MikTeX issue and not just an issue with my PC this should probably be reported at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues

Comment: Possibly related to https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/541

Comment: Properly reported at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/546

Comment: Yes, I'm using MikTex, and I did update recently (this morning). I should have added this.

Comment: Ah, then it is quite probably a MikTeX bug that was introduced recently probably in the code for https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/541. Don't worry about not mentioning 'everything' in the question at first: It's not always entirely obvious what is relevant. (But you may still want to edit your question now to include the information to make sure people see it immediately.)

Comment: The change in the `.aux` file should be harmless (the newer definition is less likely to fail in very obscure circumstances than the old one). I think the real problem is related to a recent change in MikTeX's BibTeX binary, so nothing we can fix from the LaTeX side.

Comment: A workaround would be to use `\input` instead of `\include` for now (of course you won't be able to use `\includeonly` and all the other fancy `\include` features and `\input` won't start a new page; but at least things should compile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a short-lived bug in MikTeX 7440 that came as a result of the changes for https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/541. See https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/546 for the bug report.

The issue was resolved with the MikTeX updates from 2020-05-19. An updated BibTeX that does not have the bug any more identifies as

```
MiKTeX-BibTeX 2.9.7444 (0.99d) (MiKTeX 2.9.7440 64-bit)
```

when you call `bibtex --version`.

Comment: Great, thanks for reporting the bug !