# Problem with references using apacite bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, citing, texstudio, apacite

I'm having problems whith my references it looks like I'm not doing nothing wrong but when I run my file I get this errors and my citations appear like they don't exist.
[image: errors that I'm having]

These are the error messages I'm having:

```
    I couldn't open auxiliary file justification.aux
    ---line 13 of file Proposal.aux
     : \@input{justification.aux
     :                          }
    I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
    I couldn't open auxiliary file goals.aux
    ---line 14 of file Proposal.aux
     : \@input{goals.aux
     :                  }
    I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
    I couldn't open auxiliary file lit_review.aux
    ---line 15 of file Proposal.aux
     : \@input{lit_review.aux
     :                       }
    I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
    I found no \citation commands---while reading file Proposal.aux
    (There were 4 error messages)

    Process exited with error(s)


    Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Proposal".tex

    Process exited normally
```

This is my code. As you can see I'm using apacite package. The IDE I'm using is TexStudio, I have not touched its default settings.

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Tipo de letra palatino
\usepackage{mathpazo}
% Para tablas chidas
\usepackage{booktabs}
% Herramientas para ecuaciones
\usepackage{mathtools}
% Para citaciones en estilo APA
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\section{Marco teórico}
\subsection{Problema de asignación}
El problema de asignación clásico se ocupa de designar a los trabajadores con diversas tareas o habilidades. La variación de dicha habilidad afecta
el costo de completar una tarea. La meta es determinar la asignación a un costo mínimo
de los trabajadores a las diferentes tareas. El modelo de asignación general con n trabajadores
y n tareas está representado en el cuadro 5.1. El elemento $C_{ij}$ representa el costo de
asignar el trabajador $ i $  la tarea $ j (i,j = 1, 2, 3,…, n) $. No se pierde la generalidad al suponer que la cantidad de trabajadores y la de las tareas son iguales, porque siempre
podemos agregar trabajadores o tareas ficticias para satisfacer esta suposición \cite{Taha2012}.
\bibliography{referencias}
\end{document}
```

My referencias.bib file looks like:

```
    @article{Drexl1997,
        abstract = {This contribution summarizes recent work in the field of lot sizing and scheduling. The objective is not to give a compre- hensive literature survey, but to explain differences of formal models and to provide some first readings recommendations. Our focus is on capacitated, dynamic, and deterministic cases. To underscore the importance of the research efforts, current practice is described and its shortcomings are exposed. Mathematical programming models where the planning horizon is subdivided into several discrete periods are given for both approaches that are well-established and approaches which may represent tomorrow's state of the art. Two research directions are discussed in more detail: continuous time models and multi-level lot sizing and scheduling. The paper concludes with some advice for future research activities.},
        author = {Drexl, a. and Kimms, A.},
        doi = {10.1016/S0377-2217(97)00030-1},
        file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/vicma/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Drexl, Kimms - 1997 - Lot sizing and scheduling—Survey and extensions.pdf:pdf},
        isbn = {0377-2217},
        issn = {03772217},
        journal = {European Journal of Operational Research},
        keywords = {1,Batching and scheduling problem,Capacitated lot sizing problem,Continuous setup lot sizing problem,Discrete lot sizing and scheduling problem,Lot sizing,Production planning,Proportional lot sizing and scheduling problem,Scheduling,background and motivation,batching and scheduling problem,capacitated lot sizing problem,continuous setup lot sizing,discrete lot sizing and,l e m context,lot sizing,p r o b,problem,production planning,proportional lot sizing and,scheduling,scheduling problem},
        mendeley-groups = {Aulas,Revis{\~{a}}o Bibliogr{\'{a}}fica/Revis{\~{o}}es,Bib. ProjetoF.,Revis{\~{a}}o Bibliogr{\'{a}}fica},
        number = {2},
        pages = {221--235},
        title = {{Lot sizing and scheduling — Survey and extensions}},
        url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221797000301},
        volume = {99},
        year = {1997}
    }

    @book{Taha2012,
        address = {Mexico},
        author = {Taha, Hamdy A.},
        edition = {9a},
        editor = {{L{\'{o}}pez Ballesteros}, Gabriela},
        file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/vicma/Google Drive/EBooks/Hamdy A. Taha-Investigaci{\'{o}}n de Operaciones-Pearson (2012).pdf:pdf},
        isbn = {9786073207966},
        mendeley-groups = {Libros},
        pages = {824},
        publisher = {Pearson Educaci{\'{o}}n},
        title = {{Investigaci{\'{o}}n de Operaciones}},
        year = {2012}
    }
```

Comment: If you are using MikTeX this is quite possibly related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/544949/35864 and the bug reported at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/546. The problem is being worked on.

Comment: A temporary work-around might be to replace all `\include`s with `\input`s (of course you won't be able to use advanced `\include` features like `\includeonly`).

Comment: The bug has been resolved: Update your system (you may possibly have to wait a bit until the update propagates to your mirror). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/544949/35864