# Master's thesis template no longer compiling. Works on overleaf, not on TexWorks (MikTeX 2.9)

Tags: compiling, texworks, miktex2.9

For my Bachelor thesis I used this template:

https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

I would like to do the same for my Master thesis. However, there seems to be a dependency on a package that is no longer supported or some other problem causing it to no longer compile.

For your info, the console log starts with:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7440 64-bit)
entering extended mode
```

and ends with:

```
Output written on main.pdf (31 pages, 211791 bytes).
SyncTeX written on main.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on main.log.
I couldn't open auxiliary file Chapters/Chapter1.aux
---line 33 of file main.aux
: \@input{Chapters/Chapter1.aux
: }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I couldn't open auxiliary file Appendices/AppendixA.aux
---line 46 of file main.aux
: \@input{Appendices/AppendixA.aux
: }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Biblatex version: 3.13
(There were 2 error messages)
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.
```

When trying to compile the chapter1.tex I get the error:

```
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-05-15>
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \chapter
{Chapter Title Here} % Main chapter title
?
```

Do you have any idea on how to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't compile `chapter1.tex` on its own. That will not work and has never worked. The problem you are experiencing is quite probably the same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/544949/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/544994/35864 which is also reported at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/546. For now you'll have to work on Overleaf or replace all `\inlcude`s with `\input`s.

Comment: The bug has been resolved: Update your system (you may possibly have to wait a bit until the update propagates to your mirror). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/544949/35864

Comment: I see the problem.  You are writing a Bachelor thesis but the template is for Master's thesis.

Comment: Thanks for the help @moewe. Since the update the file compiles without errors when using \include, but the content does not show up in the .pdf.
The \input workaround does the trick though!

Comment: Mhh, that is odd. All tests related to this issue that I ran compile without error and show the expected output. If you want to get `\include` going again, please ask a new question with more details and ideally a short example document that shows what you are doing and how things are going wrong.